# How to Calculate Percentages of Free Space

Tags: vbscript

I got a script which obtains disk space usage of servers. How to get the output in a table with free space percentage?

Below is the code:

```
strComputer = "Computer Name"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
'Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root'\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where drivetype=" & HARD_DISK)

str = str & "SERVER 1 - " & strComputer & vbcrlf
str = str & vbcrlf

For Each objDiskC in colDisks
str = str & objDiskC.DeviceID & " " & FormatNumber(objDiskC.Size/1073741824,2) & " GB" & vbcrlf & vbtab & vbtab
str = str & objDiskC.DeviceID & " " & FormatNumber(objDiskC.FreeSpace/1073741824,2) & " GB" & vbcrlf
Next

str = str & vbcrlf
str = str & vbcrlf
'====================================================================

'Wscript.Echo str

'Send the email
SendMail "xxx@xxx.com", "xxx@xxx.com", "*** Free Disk Space Summary ***", str
'
```

Comment: This is not easy to answer because you are not describing in which environment you are running this script (cscript, wscript, IE) and where you want the table. In the resulting Mail body or at the script side? EDIT: Is your question focused on how to create a table or how to calculate the percentage free disk space?

Comment: This is vbs script i will get a result in mail like below
SERVER 1 - server

C: 39.90 GB
C: 23.24 GB
E: 6.00 GB
E: 1.90 GB
G: 100.00 GB
G: 15.91 GB
H: 10.00 GB
H: 9.85 GB
I want to get this as 

SERVER 1 - name

Total Space   Free Space
C: 39.90 GB   C: 23.24 GB
E: 6.00 GB    E: 1.90 GB
G: 100.00 GB  G: 15.91 GB
H: 10.00 GB   H: 9.85 GB

Comment: @Bharanivel Clear as mud, so you want to display the percentage of freespace basically as text?

Comment: @Bharanivel `(objDiskC.FreeSpace / objDiskC.Size) * 100` is your percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to calculate the percentage of free-space.

The calculation for this is simply;

```vb
(objDiskC.FreeSpace / objDiskC.Size) * 100
```

Here have added an extra line to the `For Next` loop to denote the percentage.

```vb
For Each objDiskC in colDisks
  str = str & objDiskC.DeviceID & " " & FormatNumber(objDiskC.Size/1073741824, 2) & " GB" & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab
  str = str & objDiskC.DeviceID & " " & FormatNumber(objDiskC.FreeSpace/1073741824, 2) & " GB" & vbCrLf
  'Added this line to your For loop.
  str = str & objDiskC.DeviceID & " " & FormatNumber((objDiskC.FreeSpace / objDiskC.Size) * 100, 2) & "% Free" & vbCrLf
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a `HTML Table`. You could also insert a CSS `style` snippet to the HTML Mail body which sets the margins / paddings inside the table.

For this small solution I would suggest to use string interpolation for creating `table`, `tr`, `td` and the `style` element. Then use the well known way to make the percentage value out of the absolute sizes.

Have a look at [MDN - Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) on how to use it.

Comment: This is just a VBS script. where we will get a mail stating drive space in a single click.